# How do I select all text within a div and a href

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML such as:

```
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Country 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Capital 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Population</a>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to use Javascript (not jquery) to create an array:

[Country 1,Captial 1,Population]

I know the class of the DIV above each href will be set to "mt brn" - so I'd like it to ignore any a href text that isn't contained within the

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: You need to use `innerHTML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll('.mt.brn a');` to get anchor tag inside the class `.mt.brn`.Then loop throught the elements and  use inneHTML to get the content.Or use `textContent` to get the text

```js
var elemts = document.querySelectorAll('.mt.brn a');
var textArray=[];
for(var i= 0;i< elemts.length;i++){

  textArray.push(elemts[i].innerHTML )
}
console.log(textArray)
```

```html
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Country 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Capital 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Population</a>
</div>
```

Example using text Content:

```js
var elemts = document.querySelectorAll('.mt.brn a');
var textArray=[];
for(var i= 0;i< elemts.length;i++){

  textArray.push(elemts[i].textContent )
}
console.log(textArray)
```

```html
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Country 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Capital 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Population</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll('.mt.brn > a');
var contents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < anchorElements.length; i++) {
  contents.push(anchorElements[i].textContent);
}

console.log(contents);
```

```html
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Country 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Capital 1</a>
</div>
<div class="mt brn">
  <a href="....">Population</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following javascript code :

```
var divList = document.getElementsByClassName("brn"); 
var tab=[]; 
for (index = 0; index < divList.length; ++index)  { 
    var text =divList[index].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
    tab.push(text);
}
```